# Swift 3 trying to do conditional with string

Tags: swift3

I have the following code that was working great in swift 2.3

```
"code": self.searchByCode == true ? description : NSNull(),
```

In Swift 3 Im getting this error.[image]

Any clue?

Comment: You should not be using `NSNull()` in Swift.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that this expression `self.searchByCode == true ? description : NSNull()` can result in either a `String` or `NSNull`, so the compiler can't infer it's type.

You can store it in a `Any` variable before adding it to the dict or you could try this (I think this could work but I haven't tried it):

`(self.searchByCode == true ? description : NSNull()) as Any`

Comment: The first part is correct, but using `Any` is **definitely** not the way to go.

Comment: @Alexander While I agree that using `Any` is not ideal, there are legitimate uses for it. For example, if the dictionary is going to be serialized into a JSON and you want to have a key with a null value.

Comment: So use an optional. There is **no reason** to be using `NSNull` in Swift.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using `nil` instead of `NSNull()` especially you are using the Swift 3 as the following:

```
self.searchByCode == true ? description : nil
```

And it should make the error goes away.